# python - TypeError: tuple indices must be integers

Tags: python, integer, tuples, pygame, indices

I don't get what's wrong. I'll post the part of the code that's relevant.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\pygame\hygy.py", line 104, in <module>
    check_action()
  File "C:\Python\pygame\hygy.py", line 71, in check_action
    check_portal()
  File "C:\Python\pygame\hygy.py", line 75, in check_portal
    if [actor.x - 16, actor.y - 16] > portal[i][0] and [actor.x + 16, actor.y + 16] < portal[i][0]:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers
```

function:

```
def check_portal():
    for i in portal:
        if [actor.x - 16, actor.y - 16] > portal[i][0] and [actor.x + 16, actor.y + 16] < portal[i][0]:
            if in_portal == False:
                actor.x,actor.y=portal[i][1]
                in_portal = True
        elif [actor.x - 16, actor.y - 16] > portal[i][1] and [actor.x + 16, actor.y + 16] < portal[i][1]:
            if in_portal == False:
                actor.x,actor.y=portal[i][1]
                in_portal = True
        else:
            in_portal = False
```

initializing actor:

```
class xy:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
actor = xy()
```

initializing portal:

```
portal = [[100,100],[200,200]],[[300,300],[200,100]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the initialisation of `portal`, the loop

```
for i in portal:
    ...
```

will only do two iterations.  In the first iteration, `i` will be `[[100,100],[200,200]]`. Trying to do `portal[i]` will be equivalent to `portal[[[100,100],[200,200]]]`, and this doesn't make sense.  You probably just want to use `i` instead of `portal[i]`.  (You probably want to rename it to something more meaningful than `i`, too.)

Answer (score 1):

When you said `for i in portal`, in each iteration, instead of the indices in `portal` which you may think of, `i` is actually elements of `portal`. So it is not integer and causes error in `portal[i][0]`.

So a quick fix is just replace that with `for i in xrange(len(portal))`, in which `i` is indices.

Answer (score 0):

Within the for loop, `i = ([100, 100], [200, 200])`, which is not a valid index for a list.

Given the comparison in the if statements, it looks like your intention was more like:

```
for coords in portal:
   if [actor.x - 16, actor.y - 16] > coords[0] and [actor.x + 16, actor.y + 16] < coords[0]:
```

where `coords[0] == [100, 100]` on the first iteration of the loop.